# Struts 2 conditional div tag

Tags: struts2, ognl, struts-tags

I am working on my website and trying to print out portfolio objects from the database. The page where I print them out to has pagination.

I use a script to create a new page when the following tag is used:

```html
<div class="pics">
...
</div>
```

A maximum of 8 anchor tags only should go inside the above div. The anchor tags aren't anything special, they do use `<s:property>` tags but that's about it.

In order to achieve this functionality, I've tried the following:

```html
<c:set var="counter" value="0"/>
<s:iterator value="allPortfolio">
    <c:if test="${(counter mod 8) == 0}">
        <div class="pics">
   </c:if>

   <a href="<s:property value="filename">">Download</a>

    <c:if test="${(counter mod 8) == 0}">
        </div>
    </c:if>

    <c:set var="counter" value="${counter+1}"/>

</s:iterator>
```

This code, however, creates 11 pages (1 per portfolio object in my database). Where it should create just 2 pages with 8 items on the first and the remaining 3 on the second.

In other words, there should be just 2 of

```html
<div class="pics">
...
</div>
```

One with 8 anchor tags in and one with 3 anchor tags in.

Instead, this is the code that gets created once the page loads:

```html
 <div class="pics">
     <a href="1ba918625bca57f6e059c2d05393010b04da5ed6.png">Download</a>
 </div>
 <a href="ec49d4ca243a481b7fa819dfea783e0dd8f5a431.jpg">Download</a>   
 <a href="1b4ab5a3bebdf88045ef3818e852185c86e33048.png">Download</a>
 <a href="e12eaed32a97bb78ddd863696ca510d943c4d978.png">Download</a>
 <a href="2b6ee029b3fcef21b0a220a6b14de16206ce588b.png">Download</a>
 <a href="e3e94e7ac6bfb09ca012d30912525848f2d361ed.png">Download</a>
 <a href="f07e24b31fb65e38aa3d4bbe97a24a71c281aae7.png">Download</a>
 <a href="dd41b536ca45642fa9827311498b9480d6df9be8.png">Download</a>
 <div class="pics">
     <a href="a2ad0d4b73daa3311e9f9b16dcd7d9476cd6e748.png">Download</a>
 </div>
 <a href="45fa47125a5dfe3608d6d80fb0a9ba1f5c444264.png">Download</a>
 <a href="ee9b1571aa22e935772792ac363cc95e2a77bdfd.png">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't need that counter because Struts2 `<s:iterator>` tag has `status` attribute exactly for that. Define it and you can use various properties of it inside iterator. For example `index` will return current count of iterations starting from 0. The `first` property is boolean that indicates that it is the first available item in the iteration.

BTW don't forget to close your tags.

```
<s:iterator value="allPortfolio" status="stat">
  <s:if test="#stat.first">
    <div class="pics">
  </s:if>
  <s:if test="!#stat.first && #stat.index % 8 == 0">
    </div>
    <div class="pics">
  </s:if>

  <a href="<s:property value="filename"/>">Download</a>

  <s:if test="#stat.last">
    </div>
  </s:if>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: This ends with a <div class="pics"> which disturbs the div integrity of the page

Comment: @ThreaT: Forgot last closing div. :)

Comment: perfect, thanks. The only thing I'd want more is to have a safe guard against allPortfolio consisting of 0 objects. When I use an empty list, it seems to disturb the div integrity again.

Comment: @ThreaT: Just put your iterator in if block checking list emptiness.

Answer (score 0):

Using modulus of 8 means that every eight link will be divisible by 8 with 0 remainder. It's not the way to solve your problem.

You'd want to use something like:

```
<c:set var="counter" value="0" />

<s:iterator value="allPortfolio">
  <c:if test="${counter gt 7}">
    <c:set var="counter" value="0" />
  </c:if>

  <c:if test="${counter eq 0}">
      <div class="pics">
  </c:if>

  <a href="<s:property value="filename">">Download</a>

  <c:if test="${counter eq 7}">
      </div>
  </c:if>

  <c:set var="counter" value="${counter+1}" />
</s:iterator>

<c:if test="{counter ne 8}">
  </div>
</c:if>
```

The last bit is for closing the last div, in case it was left open.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<s:set var="countdown" value="0"/>
<s:iterator value="allPortfolio" status="status">

  <s:if test="#status.index % 8 == 0">
    <div class="pics">
    <s:set var="countdown" value="7"/> 
  </s:if>

   <a href="<s:url value='%{filename}'/>">Download</a>

   <s:if test="#countdown == 0 || #status.last">
     </div>
   </s:if>

   <s:set var="countdown" value="%{#countdown-1}"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: This puts them all on one page because it doesn't create the initial  <div class="pics"> tag.

Comment: @ThreaT How about now?